# Jquery: run function if the value of a hidden field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few hidden fields (lets say they all have a class name called "my-field"). The moment the value of one of these fields changes, I want to run a function.

I tried to do it this way, but it isn't working, and I suspect it is because I'm dealing with hidden fields? Or am I just doing something wrong?

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.my-field',
        function () {
            // my code goes here    
        }
);
```

Comment: Why not go to the function changing the field?

Comment: Anyway: [Basic investigation works](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+onchange+hidden+input+site:stackoverflow.com)